# How do I return the difference between a list of dictionaries and a list of objects based on a specific key:value only

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to update entries from a table based on the difference between existing entries and what the user passes.

For example:

what is passed:

```
users: [
    {"id": 1, "email": "email1@gmail.com"}, 
    {"id": 2, "email": "email2@gmail.com"}
]
```

and what already exists:

```
user_playground = UserPlaygroundModel.query.filter_by(playground=playground).all()

# This will be a list of UserPlayground objects
user_playground = [
    {id=1, playground=sandbox},
    {id=3, playground=sandbox}
]
```

So this means 1 stays in the table, 2 will be added and 3 will be deleted.

I want to output the difference between what was passed and what already exists and then change the entries based on that.

```
users_to_add = {id=2, "email": "email2@gmail.com"}

users_to_delete = {id=3}
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: what is the desired output of that two ? what do you mean with 2 will be added and 3 will be deleted

Comment: I think he wants to retain the outputs of user_playground based on an AND operation between the `id`s of users and user_playground

Comment: so, you have a list that is passed by user (`a`), and a list that is from the db (`b`)?

Comment: `set([1,2])-set([1,3])` gives `{2}` (add), and `set([1,3])-set([1,2])` gives `{3}` (delete), and `set([1,3]) & set([1,2])` gives `{1}`  (stay)

Comment: @Artog yes. I query the database based on the playground name which has a one to many relationship with users. Then I am trying to delete the users that were not passed and add users that did not exists before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly I think this is what you need:

```
users = [
    {"id": 1, "email": "email1@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2, "email": "email2@gmail.com"}
]

user_play =[
    {"id":1, "playground": "sandbox"},
    {"id":3, "playground": "sandbox"}
]


users_to_add = [u for u in users if u.get('id') not in [x.get('id') for x in user_play]]

users_to_delete = [u for u in user_play if u.get('id') not in [x.get('id') for x in users]]

print(users_to_add) # output : [{'id': 2, 'email': 'email2@gmail.com'}]

print(users_to_delete) # output : [{'id': 3, 'playground': 'sandbox'}]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TeaZulo great glad I could help you

Comment: Is there a way to return specific keys only instead of all of them in the same loop? For example instead of

`print(users_to_delete) # output : [{'id': 3, 'playground': 'sandbox', "capacity": 32}]`

return only
`print(users_to_delete) # output : [{'id': 3, "capacity": 32}]`

Comment: @TeaZulo of course yes, you can try something like this:

t = [{'id': 3, 'playground': 'sandbox', "capacity": 32}]


temp = [{k,v} for k,v in t[0].items() if k != "playground"] # note that t is a list that's why using t[0] will give you the first dictionary in the list. the Implementation would be different if you have only dictionaries. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The users that you need to add are "all users that I got from my post that are not in the database". Similarly the users that you want to delete are "all users that I have in my database that i didn't get in my post".

This can be achieve in python using there two lines:

```
# All users supplied from post body (i guess?) that is not in the db
users_to_add = [u for u in users_from_post if u.id not in [x.id for x in user_playground]]

# All users from db that was not supplied by the post (i think?)
users_to_delete = [u for u in user_playground if u.id not in [x.id for x in users_from_post]]
```

There can be things done to optimise this if you have ALOT of users, but the idea is correct.

Comment: I query the database based on the playground name which has a one to many relationship with users. Then I am trying to delete the users that were not passed and add users that did not exists before.

You are correct, however the body has keys that the user_playground does not have and vise versa so if I do that it just returns everything instead of the difference by ID.

Comment: Exactly, assuming that the `users` list is comming from some post or something, then this should give you two lists that you hace use to delete/add

Comment: I'll just edit to clarify this, and also just opt for directly comparing by id right away as im guessing object references aint the same